# Orcale Timestamp in Sync as input for Incremental Sync

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have a table in a Oracle DB. This contains a column named "change_date" with the data type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE.

We are using the following ODBC driver: ojdbc10-19.16.0.0.jar. We are on prem.

I would like to use the column as input for the "incremental" functionality of the Sync.
The problem is, that by default the field is interpreted as String.
I try to cast the the field to timestamp as well but again this seems not to be usable in Foundry.

```
select to_timestamp_tz(
           change_date,
           'RR.mm.dd hh24:mi:ss,FF6TZH:TZM'
         ) as change_date_ts,         
        change_date                  
from "myDB"."myTable"
```

This statement gives me 2 columns:

- change_date_ts: data type "other" value
  oracle.sql.TIMESTAMPTZ@7c278b6b
- change_date: data type varchar: value
  "23.01.21 23:38:14,387625 +01:00"

I can use neither value as an sensible input for an incremental sync. I do need this though, as the table is too large for snapshoting. Ideally I need Foundry to interpret this as a timestamp.
When I run the sync and store it in the dataset both columns appear as String.

Can you advice me what to do?

Comment: I know it's a work around, but any chance you could pass it as millis and use that instead?

Answer (score 0):

could one of these work?

Converting from string

`F.to_utc_timestamp(timestamp, tz)`
`F.unix_timestamp(timestamp=None, format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`

Comment: Hello MichWard, I need to obtain the timestamp in the JDBC Connection, not in the resulting Dataset.